# New Samsung S4 reloading deleted emails

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-4, samsung

I use verizon.net as my main email address.  after reading emails on my Samsung S4 and deleting them several days later they reappear as new messages.  How can I stop this from happening?

Comment: What email app are you using: stock or something else? Are you sure you have enabled account sync?

Comment: yes the account is synced, i'm basically technologically impaired...so I don't know if it's stock or something else.  It was set up at the store, and then a couple of days later started re-loading previously read and deleted emails

Answer (score 1):

Follow this [video tutorial for the Galaxy S4 stock email app](http://youtu.be/K3wsWr21j4w), and make sure you activate **Sync Email** option.

Maybe you'll have to remove and re-add your email account. Also you can try with other email account(s) you have, in order to discard an issue of Verizon's own mail servers.

Comment: thanks, yes i have two other accounts set up and neither have this issue.  I just noticed a setting called "auto resend times" under more settings for the account.  It was set at 3, i have changed it to none.  Could this have been the problem?

Comment: No, I guess this actually refers to how many times the app will try to send a message again if the first attempt fails. Try changing the value or **Sync Schedule** from **Every X minutes** to **Push** (it may drain your battery though)